# Не работает schedule при запуске flask приложения из gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, schedule

Не стартует запуск процесса schedule (использую для автоматической отправки уведомлений) при старте приложения из gunicorn (при этом остальной функционал бота работает нормально), пытался обойти это через переопределение run. Если запускать через дев сервер flask бот работает корректно. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

```
from keyboa import keyboa_maker
import config
import telebot
import inspect
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, abort
import time
import schedule
from multiprocessing.context import Process
import datetime
from ipaddress import IPv4Address
import logging
from models import execute_select_query, execute_update_query


# Дочерний класс flask с измененным run
class MyApp(Flask):
    def run(self, host=None, port=None, debug=None, load_dotenv=True, **options):
        ScheduleMessage.start_process()
        return super().run(host=host, port=port, debug=debug, load_dotenv=load_dotenv, **options)

#Класс шедуллера
class ScheduleMessage():
    def try_send_schedule(): #Бесконечный цикл для шедуллера
        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)
    def start_process(): #Создание и запуск процесса шедуллера
        p1 = Process(target=ScheduleMessage.try_send_schedule, args=())
        p1.start()

# app = Flask(__name__)
app = MyApp(__name__)

logger = telebot.logger
telebot.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

API_TOKEN = config.token

WEBHOOK_HOST = config.host
WEBHOOK_PORT = config.port # 443, 80, 88 or 8443 (port need to be 'open')Webhook_port = 5000 # 443, 80, 88 или 8443 (порт должен быть «открытым»)
WEBHOOK_LISTEN = config.listen_ip  # In some VPS you may need to put here the IP addr

WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT = config.ssl_cert  # Path to the ssl certificate
WEBHOOK_SSL_PRIV = config.ssl_priv  # Path to the ssl private key

WEBHOOK_URL_BASE = "https://%s:%s" % (WEBHOOK_HOST, WEBHOOK_PORT)
WEBHOOK_URL_PATH = "/%s/" % (API_TOKEN)

#Создание объекта бота
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)

#Маршрут для вебхука
@app.route(WEBHOOK_URL_PATH, methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    if request.headers.get('content-type') == 'application/json':
        json_string = request.get_data().decode('utf-8')
        update = telebot.types.Update.de_json(json_string)
        bot.process_new_updates([update])
        return ''
    else:
        abort(403)

#Отправка уведомления
def send_notification():
    # if datetime.datetime.now().day == 28: # Отправка напоминания о пополнении баланса каждое 28ое число
    user_data_query = 'SELECT запрос'
    res_user_data_query_table = execute_select_query(user_data_query).split('__next_item__')
    for i in range(len(res_user_data_query_table)):
        row = res_user_data_query_table[i].split('__next_column__')
        if row[0] != '':
            row = {
                'tg_id' : row[0],
                'tariff_id' : row[1],
                'id' : row[2]
            }
            res_user_data_query_table[i] = row
    for item in res_user_data_query_table:
        if isinstance(item, dict):
            try:
                balance = check_balance(item)
                monthly_query = 'SELECT запрос'
                res_monthly_query = execute_select_query(monthly_query).split('__next_item__')
                service_id_query = 'SELECT запрос'
                res_service_id_query = execute_select_query(service_id_query).split('__next_item__')
                discount_services = ['0', '1']
                if_discount_message = ''
                sum_services_price = 0.0
                for i in range(len(res_service_id_query)):
                    if res_service_id_query[i] != '':
                        service_price_query = 'SELECT запрос'
                        res_service_price_query = execute_select_query(service_price_query).split('__next_item__')
                        if res_service_id_query[i] in discount_services:
                            if_discount_message = 'Абонентская плата рассчитывается без учета скидки.'
                        sum_services_price += float(res_service_price_query[0])
                monthly = float(res_monthly_query[0]) + sum_services_price
                delta = monthly - balance
                note = ' Текст ' + if_discount_message
                if delta < 0:
                    note = ' Другой текст '
                bot.send_message(item.get('tg_id'), note)
            except telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException:
                print('no_chat with ', item.get('tg_id'))

schedule.every(30).seconds.do(send_notification) #Вызов функции отправки уведомления по расписанию

#Стартовое приветствие бота
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    chat_id = get_chat_id(message)
    logo = open(config.path_to_logo, 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(chat_id, logo, caption='Здравствуйте. Это - информационный бот.')
    menu(message)


#Удаление вебхука от предыдущего запуска бота
bot.remove_webhook()
time.sleep(0.15)

#Поднятие вебхука
bot.set_webhook(url=WEBHOOK_URL_BASE + WEBHOOK_URL_PATH, certificate=open(WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT, 'r'))

# ScheduleMessage.start_process()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(
        # host=WEBHOOK_LISTEN,
        # port=WEBHOOK_PORT,
        # ssl_context=(WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT, WEBHOOK_SSL_PRIV),
        # debug=False
        )
```

Команда запуска gunicorn

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:88 main:app --certfile=/cert.pem --keyfile=/pkey.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась с помощью apcheduler

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
sched = BackgroundScheduler(daemon=True)
sched.add_job(send_notification,'interval',seconds=30)
sched.start()
```